# Can't update CollapsingToolbar title after calling setHasOptionsMenu()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library, android-toolbar

I'm trying to update the title in a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` from a Fragment (the toolbar itself is in the Activity XML). This works fine most of the time, but when I have to add menu items from the `Fragment` as well, then it stops working and the previous title remains visible.

This is the code in my Fragment:

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

    // If I remove the line below then the title is updated just fine
    setHasOptionsMenu(true)

    activity?.collapsingToolbar?.title = ""
}
```

I found a workaround for this issue (seems like the problem is a race condition during the views drawing) by using

`Handler().post { activity?.collapsingToolbar?.title = "" }`

instead of

`activity?.collapsingToolbar?.title = ""`.

However, I don't like the fact that I have to create a `Handler` for this specific purpose, it seems like the support library should take care of the serialization of these things.

Does anyone have a better solution?